# Chain backend requests in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a paged backend service that supports basic pagination so it can provide page x from the backend.

I would like to call a service called refresh on all objects in the DB.

The first page tells me how manny pages I need to get.

From there I need to iterate over the other pages and perform. the refresh action

I would prefer to do this sequentially to do not DDOS my own server and since I can then show the user the progress of the operation.

So far I have:

```
        const pageSize = 20;
        this.service.Filter(null,null,null,1,pageSize).pipe(mergeMap(initalData => {
          const pageCount = initalData.pageInfo.pageCount;            
          let ids:string[] = initalData.payload.map(item => item.id);
          console.log('page',pageCount,1, initalData.pageInfo.page,ids);
          let ret = this.service.refresh(ids);
          for(let p=2;p<=pageCount;p++){
            console.log('refresh page', p);
            const pageResult = this.service.Filter(null,null,null,p,pageSize);
            pageResult.pipe(mergeMap(data => {
              let ids:string[] = data.payload.map(item => item.id);
              console.log('page', p, data.pageInfo.page,ids);
              const refreshResult = this.service.refresh(ids);
              return CombineLatest(ret, refreshResult);
            }));
          }                          
          return ret;
        })).subscribe(ret =>{
          console.log('final', ret);
        });
```

which only shows the log for the initial page and the final page
also the refresh only happens on the first batch of items.

EDIT:

This gets the job done but it feels like not clean code since you have to sub to every page request:

```
this.service.Filter(null,null,null,1,pageSize).pipe(mergeMap(initalData => {
          const pageCount = initalData.pageInfo.pageCount;            
          const result:Observable<any>[] = [];
          for(let p=1;p<=pageCount;p++){

            console.log('page', p);
            this.service.Filter(null,null,null,p,pageSize).subscribe(data => {
              if(data && data.payload) {
                let ids:string[] = data.payload.map(item => item.id);
                console.log('page',data.pageInfo.page, ids);
                let pageResult = this.service.refresh(ids);
                pageResult.subscribe();
                result.push(pageResult);
              }
            });                
          }                          
          return combineLatest(result);
        })).subscribe(ret =>{
          console.log('final', ret);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, `forkJoin` RxJS operator may be helpful in your case.
This operator combines results of multiple HTTP requests. You get a tupil value from `forkJoin` operator. Multiple requests are performed in parallel, but tupil value is only emitted when all of these observables are completed.

Useful links to read more about this topic:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: as far as I know `forkJoin` is depricated

Comment: ```forkJoin(observable1, observable2)``` > WORKING - deprecation warning
```forkJoin([observable1, observable2])``` > WORKING - no warning.
Pass an array like this